# Xtrareport summary not lie next to the detail?

Tags: winforms, layout, devexpress, xtrareport

I am using XtraReport with **detail** band and **summary** band. In the design, I put the **detail** next to the **summary**, but when the report was generated, the **summary** is long distance from the **detail**, I think I is flow to the bottom of report, how can I make the **summary** lie next to the **detail** like design mode?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What type of band is the summary row in?

Some bands have a `Print At Bottom` property within the bands parameters, ensure this is set to No if it is a ReportFooter type band.

[image]

Comment: Thank, I miss a band with Bottom margin,I put my things in Bottom margin so I made the problem. To solve it, just create a footer band and "Print at bottom" set to false, thank again